# Is there an API which exposes the paths searched by the start command?

Tags: batch-file, winapi, cmd

What paths are searched by `start`?  Is this path list queryable via WMI, the registry, WSH shell folder constants, .NET methods, or any other Windows API?

In a `cmd` console, the `start` command is sort of magic.  Say your default web browser is Firefox.  You also have Chrome and Opera installed, but they are neither set as default, nor associated with any file types, nor in your %PATH%.  Considering the following example:

```js
start "" opera https://stackoverflow.com
```

... why does that work?

[image: mind blown]

The reason this matters is that, for all the `start` command's strengths, it is still perilous to retrieve an application's PID or window handle when that application was launched with `start`.  In a `cmd` environment I'd prefer to use `wmic process call create` in a `for /F` loop to capture the PID.  So is there a way I can teach `wmic process call create` to launch "opera" or "iexplore" or "outlook" or "winword" or other applications as `start` can without fully qualifying the `drive:\\path\\to\\executable`?

I thought I was on to a solution by scanning `HKLM\Software\Clients` recursively for `shell\open\command`, then adding each referenced location temporarily to %PATH%:

```js
rem // temp add installed clients to %PATH% to make "call :display" behave like "start"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (HKLM HKCU) do for /f "tokens=2*" %%I in (
    'REG QUERY %%a\Software\Clients /s /f command /k /ve ^| find "(Default)"'
) do if "%%~I"=="REG_EXPAND_SZ" (
    if /i "%%~xJ"==".exe" (
        if "!PATH:%%~J\..=!"=="!PATH!" path !PATH!;%%~J\..
    ) else for %%# in (%%J) do if /i "%%~x#"==".exe" (
        if "!PATH:%%~#\..=!"=="!PATH!" path !PATH!;%%~#\..
    )
) else (
    if /i "%%~xJ"==".exe" (
        if "!PATH:%%~dpJ=!"=="!PATH!" path !PATH!;%%~dpJ
    ) else (
        for %%# in (%%J) do if /i "%%~x#"==".exe" (
            if "!PATH:%%~dp#=!"=="!PATH!" path !PATH!;%%~dp#
        )
    )
)
endlocal & path %PATH%
```

That works reasonably well, but it still falls short of what `start` can access.  For example:

```js
start "" wordpad
```

works, whereas

```js
wmic process call create "wordpad.exe"
```

fails.

Comment: The start command will search this registry path if memory serves me correctly. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

Comment: Also type `path`, `path /?`, and `dpath /?` (the last was for making Dos 1 programs work with Dos 2 operating system).

Comment: What is your plan in case you find multiple locations for an executable?

Comment: @lit The script I was writing that prompted this question was already employing PowerShell hybrid code for a P/Invoke function. I took Noodles' advice and used `ShellExecute` (by way of the `Start-Process` cmdlet) as an alternative to `start`. I guess it goes by order of current working dir then %path% then App Paths. Basically, I'm not planning consciously, but just leaving it to chance and trusting the user to take a long walk off a short pier if he doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember a discussion about this very topic either on DosTips.com or here on SO but I cannot find it.  Hopefully somebody does so we can mark this question as a duplicate.

We know that the batch files will search the current directory and then the path variable to find an executable.  The `START` command also searches the following Registry path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

So you have a few options to find the executable.

You can use the `WHERE` command which searches the current directory and the directories in the PATH variable.

```
where notepad.exe
```

You can also just search the path variable with a `FOR` command.

```
for %%I in (notepad.exe) do echo %%~$PATH:I
```

And of course you can search the registry path as I mentioned above by doing a REG QUERY.

Comment: Neither you nor I can find it if it has already been asked on SO.  Probably best not to mark this post as a duplicate.  Maybe how I have my question worded will be a little friendlier for searches?  In any case, `reg query "%apppaths%" /s /f "%exe%" /k /ve | find "(Default)"` seems to match the behavior of `start` in the limited testing I've done, and also lets me reduce that 20-line code snippet in my question down to just 3 lines.  Much obliged!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit2**

This may be of interest regards to what you are doing (as opposed to why something works the way it does).

From a previous answer

[Can I create shorthand names for use inside cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956072/can-i-create-shorthand-names-for-use-inside-cmd)

> See `Doskey /?`.
>
> You could do this  `doskey cddesk=cd "%userprofile%\desktop"`
>
> Then type `cddesk`.
>
> By putting all your macros in a batch file you can autoload. Of course
>   you could do this with batchfiles too.
>
> From Technical Reference to the Windows 2000 Registry, Microsoft,
>   2000.
>
> `AutoRun  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
>
> Data type Range Default value
>
> REG_SZ list of commands There is no default value for this entry.
>
> Description
>
> Contains commands which are executed each time you start Cmd.exe.
>
> Also see this batchfile https://pastebin.com/A2qLw8r3 that list
>   special names.
>
> In a command prompt `start shell:desktop`
>
> Or in Start - Run (Winkey + R) just `shell:desktop`

**Edit**

I'll just add some caveats here.

This is about opening executables using `Start` command. A massive amount of rules apply to non executable files.

Not using `Start` CMD pre-processes the command line and sends a FQFN to `CreateProcess` - so it's CMD that searches the path not `CreateProcess`.

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/launch is the documentation for ShellExecute. Everything ends up calling CreateProcess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw. Plus CMD preprocessing is detailed here https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Windows_NT_Shell_Scripting.html?id=jrdQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y. Also `start /?` provides documentation for all three ways to start files. A summary is here [Command to run a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135)

Some fun facts. CMD if it can't recognise a file extension will attempt to execute it. `ShellExecute` will content sniff unknown files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/filetype-key.

> quote from rojo: *Thanks for the link dump. I'm struggling to understand how `ShellExecute` can save me from having to fully qualify path names though. That was my primary question.* "To use ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx, your application must **specify the file or folder object that is to be acted on**, and a verb that specifies the operation." *It's the "specify the file or folder object" part that I'm asking about.*

It uses the 6 steps under CreateProcess and if that turns up nothing it uses App Paths. If a verb is not specified the default verb is used (usually Open). See my answer here [How do i automate the simulation of right clicking a file and selecting the first option using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913756/how-do-i-automate-the-simulation-of-right-clicking-a-file-and-selecting-the-firs).

So it an intersection of 4 technologies. Compatibility with MSDos, changes made by IBM for OS/2 and updated by Microsoft for Windows 2000, the standard windows way of starting programs CreateProcess, and with Windows 95 we got shell functions which are based on OLE

> quote from rojo: *Snap! You're right! In PowerShell I was able to create a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object, set `$ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $true`, and then start "wordpad" without any file extension or fully qualified path. Setting the `.UseShellExecute property` to `$false` caused the execution to fail. How interesting!*